# How to tell MySQL to trigger a Hash before Update/Insert?

Tags: python, mysql, hash, triggers, insert

I am struggeling to create a trigger within MySQL, so that everytime I am inserting a value into a column named `title` a HASH shall be created and stored in the column `title_hash`. Since I don't know how this works I found this code while googling:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertModelHash
BEFORE
  INSERT
ON
  products
FOR EACH ROW SET
  NEW.model_hash = CONV(RIGHT(MD5(NEW.products_model), 16), 16, 10)
```

The MySQL-reference tells me, that this means:

1. Create a trigger called `insertModelHash`...
2. ... before inserting row int table `products`...
3. use the functions `MD5, RIGHT, CONV` on the column `products_model` in every new row I intend to insert.

The 3. point needs more explanation:

- I guess, that `NEW` is some sort of identifier of new rows. So `NEW.products_model` points to the column `products_model` in the current (new) row.
- Then `MD5` is issued. Since I want to use SHA-2 it is obvious for me to change `MD5(NEW.products_model), 16)` ===> `SHA2(NEW.products_model), 224)`.
- **And now I struggle: Why does this guy use `CONV(RIGHT(...)...)`? Is this really necessary?**

Additional information: Right now, I am doing

```
hashlib.sha224(title).hexdigest()
```

in Python and store this value.

I appreciate any suggestions/explanations!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your three questions:

The `NEW` keyword references the 'pseudo-table' for the record that would be inserted. On an updated trigger, you can access both 'NEW' and 'OLD', and on a delete, just 'OLD'.

Yes, MD5 is used to create the hash. However, in your question, you have part of the parameter to the 'RIGHT' function included. It's only `MD5(NEW.products_model)` (there's no `, 16)`. And yes, you can substitute SHA2 for MD5, if it's available (it's only available if MySQL is configured for SSL support).

The `RIGHT(string, number)` simply takes the right 'number' characters from 'string'.
The CONV() function is used to convert a number between bases. The combination of these last two functions takes the right 16 characters of the hash, and converts them from base 16 (hex) to base 10 (decimal).

And the answer is no, you don't need them if all you want to do is store the hash itself.

```
  NEW.model_hash = SHA2(NEW.products_model)
```

Comment: Just to be sure: If I call `SHA2` on `NEW.title` I will get the same result as I would get when I do `hashlib.sha224(title).hexdigest()` in Python?

Comment: The first couple of paragraphs here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html talk about the return values. The short answer is a qualified yes. The caveat being that depending on the version of mysql you're using, the return value may either be a binary string or a character string. Either way, I don't really think you need to do much other than store it in a varchar field, and it will be converted, but I would run a test on a known value between the two sources to be sure.